# PJSIP call pjsua_destroy() block main thread

Tags: ios, voip, pjsip

Hang-up a video call, call the `pjsua_call_hangup()` method return successfully;

Use `pjsua_destroy()` method to destroy pjsua instance and other resource,
then the application is frozen,

here is the callstack:

[image]

BTW, I was call `pj_thread_register` on main-thread context.

Comment: had the same issue, ended with just never calling pjsua_destroy(). Was initializing it in the start of the app and never deinitilizing.

Comment: @Oleg Hi, I was able to solve this problem by call the `pjsua_destroy()` in another background thread.